# General threshold-independent statistics

Tags: machine-learning, auc, threshold

apologies in advance for my bad statistics. I am trying to evaluate two models based on their adverse impact ratio (AIR), which is defined as
$$
AIR = \frac{\text{approval rate for protected class}}{\text{approval rate for control class}}
$$
The approval rate is determined by a threshold parameter (approve if the model score is $> t, t \in [0, 1)$. AIR is better if it is closer to 1. I wanted to come up with a threshold-independent way of evaluating AIR, similar to ROC-AUC. Simply taking the mean across all thresholds feels wrong, as it feels like certain thresholds are more important (I don't really care about the AIR at a threshold of .1), but using a weighted average just introduces more hyperparameters. I also thought about graphing AIR against the threshold values, and taking the area under the curve, but wasn't sure what that really means statistically. I would appreciate any help or links to relevant literature, as my googling has just turned up articles about ROC-AUC, which is what I want in spirit but doesn't map exactly to my problem.

Comment: I would suggest to work from the narrative you would build on this metric. *How would you explain that your new metric allows to compare models*? Personally I don't like AUC metrics, since I really don't care what my, e.g. precision, is at recall of around 0.2, I mostly care for recall around 0.8-0.9. Maybe there is a way for you to re-express your threshold in a more meaningful way, e.g. let threshold be the value at which top 10% of your population gets approved? Or 90% of your protected class gets approved.